# Is it possible to control android accessibility with arduino nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, android

I am trying to build an ACC device. when a button is pressed the changes should be made via android accessibility mode.
I am using arduino nano, and I don't know how to control android using arduino.

Comment: Not with a nano, unless you write some app for Android that responds to serial data.